# HTTP load failed (kCFStreamErrorDomainSSL, -9806 ( IOS9)

Tags: swift, info.plist, xcode7, ios9

I am getting the NSURLSession/NSURLConnection HTTP load failed on iOS 9 while running app on Simulator.
Here is how my info.plist file looks like

```
<key>NSAppTransportSecurity</key>
    <dict>
        <key>NSAllowsArbitraryLoads</key>
        <true/>
        <key>NSIncludesSubdomains</key>
        <true/>
        <!--Include to allow insecure HTTP requests-->
        <key>NSTemporaryExceptionAllowsInsecureHTTPLoads</key>
        <true/>
        <!--Include to specify minimum TLS version-->
        <key>NSTemporaryExceptionMinimumTLSVersion</key>
        <string>TLSv1.1</string>
    </dict>
```

Even after entering these key values Same error is showing up on the Xcode Console. please assist.

This is the screenshot of *`info.plist`*

[image]

Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to define the URL you want to apply these rules for.
You can find the correct declaration on Apple's documentation page:
https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/technotes/App-Transport-Security-Technote/

So basically your Info.plist should look like this and include the domain.

Note: for better transparency, I also redeclared the default value for `NSAllowsArbitraryLoads` to be false

```
<key>NSAppTransportSecurity</key>
<dict>
    <key>NSAllowsArbitraryLoads</key>
    <false/>
    <key>NSExceptionDomains</key>
    <dict>
        <key>yourdomain.com</key>
        <dict>
            <key>NSIncludesSubdomains</key>
            <true/>
            <key>NSAllowsArbitraryLoads</key>
            <true/>
            <key>NSTemporaryExceptionMinimumTLSVersion</key>
            <string>TLSv1.1</string>
            <key>NSTemporaryExceptionAllowsInsecureHTTPLoads</key>
            <true/>
        </dict>
    </dict>
</dict>
```

Best regards.

In case, you just don't care about all these ssl mess ups (I do not recommend this) and want to only go for debugging your UI, you can alternatively go temporarily and use the non-default for App TransportSecurity and allow just anything:

```
<key>NSAppTransportSecurity</key>
<dict>
    <key>NSAllowsArbitraryLoads</key>
    <true/>
</dict>
```

I am not sure, whether Apple would let this pass in the AppStore Review ;-)

Comment: Yes, it does pass. There are many apps which just don't know at the build time, which domains exactly will the links point to. There's good reason to have this enabled in a RSS reader etc.

Comment: i have disabled the ATS for all but, still request gets failed