# I set "Allow Arbitrary Loads" with "YES" , But getting HTTP load failed (kCFStreamErrorDomainSSL, -9806)

Tags: ios, ssl, nsurlsession

I have the following setting in my project info.plist:

```
<key>NSAppTransportSecurity</key>
<dict>
      <key>NSAllowsArbitraryLoads</key>
        <true/>
</dict>
```

But still getting the following error only with Vodafone mobile data:

> NSURLSession/NSURLConnection HTTP load failed (kCFStreamErrorDomainSSL, -9806)
>   Error Details: Error Domain=NSURLErrorDomain Code=-1200 "An SSL error has occurred and a secure connection to the server cannot be made." UserInfo={_kCFStreamErrorCodeKey=-9806, NSLocalizedRecoverySuggestion=Would you like to connect to the server anyway?, NSUnderlyingError=0x17004dfb0 {Error Domain=kCFErrorDomainCFNetwork Code=-1200 "(null)" UserInfo={_kCFStreamPropertySSLClientCertificateState=0, _kCFNetworkCFStreamSSLErrorOriginalValue=-9806, _kCFStreamErrorDomainKey=3, _kCFStreamErrorCodeKey=-9806}}, NSLocalizedDescription=An SSL error has occurred and a secure connection to the server cannot be made., NSErrorFailingURLKey=https://v1.xyz.net:8080/signup/, NSErrorFailingURLStringKey=https://v1.xyz.net:8080/signup/, _kCFStreamErrorDomainKey=3}

- Updated 
  Here is my code :

  ```
  NSString *jsonRequest=@"JSON";
  NSURL *baseURL = [NSURL URLWithString:@"https://v1.xyz.net:8080/signup/"];
  NSURLSessionConfiguration *configuration = [NSURLSessionConfiguration defaultSessionConfiguration];
  configuration.requestCachePolicy=NSURLRequestReloadIgnoringLocalCacheData;
  NSURLSession *session = [NSURLSession sessionWithConfiguration:configuration];
  NSMutableURLRequest *request = [[NSMutableURLRequest alloc] init];
  [request setHTTPMethod:@"POST"];
  [request addValue:@"application/json" forHTTPHeaderField:@"Content-Type"];
  [request addValue:@"application/json" forHTTPHeaderField:@"Accept"];
  NSData *postData = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:[jsonRequest dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding] options:0 error:nil];
  [request setURL:baseURL];
  [request setHTTPBody:postData];
  NSURLSessionDataTask *postDataTask = [session dataTaskWithRequest:request completionHandler:^(NSData *data, NSURLResponse *response, NSError *error) {
      if (!error) {
          NSDictionary *responseObject = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:data options:0 error:nil];
          NSLog(@"%@",responseObject);
      } else {
          // error code here
          NSLog(@"Error %@",error);
      }
  }];
  [postDataTask resume];
  ```

Comment: Have you [searched on the error](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bios%5D+An+SSL+error+has+occurred+and+a+secure+connection+to+the+server+cannot+be+made)?

Comment: Of course,  I did and all answers were to set "YES" for "Allow Arbitrary Loads", Also I tried this solution: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31255853/http-load-failed-kcfstreamerrordomainssl-9806-ios9

Comment: The point is, however, that you question, as posed, adds nothing new to what has already been asked and answered on SO on this topic. You haven't shown what _you_ are doing (e.g. what your _Info.plist_ actually looks like), so there is no reason to suppose that you are following instructions correctly.

Comment: Enabling "Allow Arbitrary Loads" is for http URLs, not https URLs.

Comment: These [search results](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%22%28kCFStreamErrorDomainSSL%2C+-9806%29%22+secure+connection+to+the+server+cannot+be+made) are probably more relevant.

Comment: I reopened the question because simply enabling "Allow Arbitrary Loads" is only for allowing http URLs. This question is about an SSL error with an https URL.

Answer (score 1):

The issue was from mobile operator they blocked https over port 8080, so we changed the port to use standard https port 443 and it works well.

We used the following steps to investigate the issue:

1- Checking our server certificate: 
$openssl s_client -connect https://v1.xyz.net:8080/signup/

2- Using the nscurl Tool to Diagnose ATS Connection Issues:
/usr/bin/nscurl --ats-diagnostics --verbose https://v1.xyz.net:8080/signup/

Answer (score 0):

Simply disable ATS, you can follow this steps by open Info.plist, and add the following lines:

```
<key>NSAppTransportSecurity</key> 
<dict> <key>NSAllowsArbitraryLoads</key> <true/>
</dict>
```

If still it has the same problem,it's the certificate at the server that was not signed by an authorized CA. so anyone having such kind of problem check that the certificate is valid at server end or not.

Comment: Yes, I already disabled ATS, But still getting the same error with Vodafone mobile data, even with other operators or on Wifi it is working well without any problem.

Comment: Same thing is happening for me as well. I have disabled the ATS but, still it's failing.